# Applying function that cares about index to every element of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3-Dimensional numpy array A. I would like to multiply every element A[i,j,k] by w*( i / Lx + j / Ly + k / Lz ) where w, Lx, Ly and Lz are real numbers (floats). Performing this operation in a for loop is highly impractical, since I need to be able to scale this for large arrays and a for loop over the three indices ijk scales in O(N^3).

Is there an efficient way to perform an operation on each element of a numpy array that cares about index?

Comment: Create 3 3D numpy array: I is like I[i,:,:]=i, J is like J[:,j,:]=j and K[:,:,k]=k. Then A*w*(I/Lx + J/Ly + K/Lz)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
M,N,R = A.shape

p1 = np.arange(M)[:,None,None]/Lx
p2 = np.arange(N)[:,None]/Ly
p3 = np.arange(R)/Lz

out = A/(w*(p1 + p2 + p3))
```

You can also use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) for a *more elegant* solution -

```
M,N,R = A.shape
X,Y,Z = np.ix_(np.arange(M),np.arange(N),np.arange(R))
out = A/(w*((X/Lx) + (Y/Ly) + (Z/Lz)))
```

---

Runtime tests and output verification -

Function definitions:

```
def vectorized_app1(A, w, Lx, Ly, Lz ):
    M,N,R = A.shape
    p1 = np.arange(M)[:,None,None]/Lx
    p2 = np.arange(N)[:,None]/Ly
    p3 = np.arange(R)/Lz
    return A/(w*(p1 + p2 + p3))

def vectorized_app2(A, w, Lx, Ly, Lz ):
    M,N,R = A.shape
    X,Y,Z = np.ix_(np.arange(M),np.arange(N),np.arange(R))
    return A/(w*((X/Lx) + (Y/Ly) + (Z/Lz)))

def original_app(A, w, Lx, Ly, Lz ):
    out = np.empty_like(A)
    M,N,R = A.shape
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            for k in range(R):
                out[i,j,k] = A[i,j,k]/(w*( (i / Lx) + (j / Ly) + (k / Lz) ))
    return out
```

Timings:

```
In [197]: # Inputs
     ...: A = np.random.rand(100,100,100)
     ...: w, Lx, Ly, Lz = 2.3, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2
     ...: 

In [198]: np.allclose(original_app(A,w,Lx,Ly,Lz),vectorized_app1(A,w,Lx,Ly,Lz))
Out[198]: True

In [199]: np.allclose(original_app(A,w,Lx,Ly,Lz),vectorized_app2(A,w,Lx,Ly,Lz))
Out[199]: True

In [200]: %timeit original_app(A, w, Lx, Ly, Lz )
1 loops, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop

In [201]: %timeit vectorized_app1(A, w, Lx, Ly, Lz )
10 loops, best of 3: 24.6 ms per loop

In [202]: %timeit vectorized_app2(A, w, Lx, Ly, Lz )
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop
```